# How to display two data in a single column

Tags: jsp

I have a query that gets me data as (Data A and B are in a same column)

```
KEY
===
A
B
```

And given this code,

```
<tr>
    <td>${result.key}</td>  
</tr>
```

Now, what I want is to display data it as

NEXT : "A"

PREV : "B"

How should I distinguish the A,B when they are in a same column?

Basically, I want to append "NEXT" (Hard-coding) in front of A and "PREV" (Hard-coding) in front of B.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it depends from your task, but something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>NEXT:</td>
    <td><%=result.getKey("keyName").split("separator")[0]%></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>PREV:</td>
    <td><%=result.getKey("keyName").split("separator")[1]%></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column contains following text "A\nB". Then you can create StringTokenizer and initialize it to column value and use "n" as list of tokenizers. Then you can extract both values. Other way is to use String.indexOf("\n") and split the string manually. When you have two variables, it shall be easy to render them in jsp.

PS I hope that I understood your question correctly